# On-chain text encryption using Whisper protocol

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, whisper

Could one send a 10-character encrypted message within an ERC-20 transaction using the whisper protocol ON-CHAIN?

Or could that only be achieved by running private nodes and setting up a p2p server? What other ways are there to send short encrypted messages with a token transaction?

Comment: You can add data to your transactions.